# Can any one help me to use Splice inside Push in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, splice

I am pushing an item into $scope.dt. If day is not equal to true, then that push item will splice or delete and continuously work for next item. If day is true, then no splice.

This is in my angularjs controller       :

```
  $scope.test = function() {
    $scope.dt.push({
      sel: Date,
      S: STime,
      E: Etime,
      H: Hour,
      A: day
    });

    if (day != true) {
      $scope.dt.splice(1);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not only push the item, only if your condition is true instead of first adding it and then deleting it.

```
$scope.test = function() {
    if (day) {
        $scope.dt.push({
            sel: Date,
            S: STime,
            E: Etime,
            H: Hour,
            A: day
        });
    }
}
```

try this.. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
     $scope.dates.splice(- 1, 1);
```

Answer that work for me